# Twisted Web: problems encoding unicode

Tags: python, html, http, character-encoding, twisted.web

This is probably a stupid question/problem, but i could not find an answer for it. Also, it may not realy be twisted specific.

I am trying to write a resource for a `twisted.web` webserver, which should serve a page containing non-ascii characters.
According to [this discusson](https://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2010-June/022363.html), all i need to do is to set the `Content-Type` HTTP-Header and return an encoded string.
Unfortunately, the page shows invalid characters.

Here is the code (as a `.rpy`):

```
"""a unicode test"""
from twisted.web.resource import Resource

class UnicodeTestResource(Resource):
    """A unicode test resource."""
    isLeaf = True
    encoding = "utf-8"

    def render_GET(self, request):
            text = u"unicode test\n ä ö ü ß"
            raw = u"<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Unicode encoding test</TITLE><HEAD><BODY><P>{t}</P></BODY></HTML>".format(t=text)
            enc = raw.encode(self.encoding)
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=" + self.encoding)
            return enc

resource = UnicodeTestResource()
```

The result (without the html) is: `unicode test Ã¤ Ã¶ Ã¼ Ã`.

Is this caused by an encoding mismatch between the server and the client?

I am using python 2.7.12 and twisted 17.1.0. The page has been accessed using firefox.

Sorry for my terrible english.

Thanks

**EDIT:** I found the problem. I assumed that `twisted.web.static.File` with a `ResourceScript` processor would use the encoding specified in the file in which the reactor is running.
Apparently this is not the case.
Adding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on the top of each file fixed the problem.